# Latex ignores blank space after capital letters

Tags: pdftex, texlive, linux

I am having a weird problem. When I compile my documents, Latex drops white spaces between words. This happens only after capitalized letters. For example,

```
R reports the standard OLS SE, instead of the GMM/2SLS SE.
```

is typeset in the pdf as

> Rreports the standard OLSSE, instead of the GMM/2SLSSE.

I got this PC relatively recently, and this has happened ever since. I am using TeXLive on a Linux Mint machine. I use `pdflatex` to compile my documents.

UPDATE: So I inspected that behavior a bit further. It turns out that when I initially type the text, latex ignores spaces after capitalized letters as described above. However, when I go back, delete all the spaces and re-enter them, everything works. Does anyone have a clue why that could be?

UPDATE2*: Until now I did not specify the input encoding in the header, i.e. I did NOT use

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

I tried that now, but I can't compile the document anymore. Might that be related to my original problem?

UPDATE3: I did not copy/paste any of the text, I just typed it.

---

*I am not sure how things work here, am I supposed to answer questions in the comments or edit my original question?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you add the LaTeX code you're using for typesetting that sentence?

Comment: Are you perhaps using `\R reports the standard...`? Note that spaces after control sequences or macros (like `\R`) are gobbled. You would need `\R\ reports the standard...` or consider using the [`xspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace) and define `\newcommand{\R}{\R\xspace}`.

Comment: After your update : how did you type the text first? Did you by any chance copy/paste it from elsewhere?

Comment: You probably were typing a "NON-BREAKING SPACE" character. Are you using UTF-8 as input encoding for your file?

Comment: Your last additions tell me that you mistyped a "NO-BREAK SPACE" instead of a simple space (possibly your keyboard uses Shift-Space for it). If you add `\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}` to your preamble, such characters will be flagged with errors and it will be easy to find them.

Answer (score 2):

Your last additions tell me that you mistyped a "NO-BREAK SPACE" instead of a simple space (possibly your keyboard uses Shift-Space for it). If you add

```
\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}
```

to your preamble, such characters will be flagged with errors and it will be easy to find them.